# animate imageview when image from server is attached volley android

Tags: android, animation, android-volley

I am using `Volley networking library` for my network calls

Of volley I am using `NetworkImageview` for loading the image from server.

I wanted to animate my `NetworkImageview` when the image from server is attached. **not on the default image**

my code

```
imgCoverPhoto.setScaleX(1.3f);
imgCoverPhoto.setScaleY(1.3f);
imgCoverPhoto.setAlpha(0.5f);
imgCoverPhoto.setImageUrl(coverUri, imageLoader);
imageLoader.get(coverUri, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
@Override
public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
if (response != null) {
    animate1(imgCoverPhoto, true);
   }
}

  @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       }});
```

**This animate even on the default image**